# Invalid use of non-static data member (typedef map)

Tags: c++, typedef

In my header file, I have

```
    typedef map <string, MyClass*> myMap;

    class MainClass {
      myMap map;
    public:
      friend istream& operator>> (istream &is, MainClass &mainc) {
        string name = "Geo";
        MyClass* sample = new MyClass();
        map.insert(myMap::value_type(name, sample) );
        return is; }
    };
```

During compilation, I get:

```
line 4: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'MainClass::map'
line 9: error: from this location
```

I have tried changing myMap map to myMap mapa but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: `map` is a bad choice of variable name as it hides `std::map`, which you seem to have pulled into this namespace.  Try a more meaningful identifier instead.

Comment: why your operator >> is made as a method and as a friend at the same time  ?

Comment: @Andrew: This is perfectly legitimate -- putting the definition of the friend function inside the class produces pretty much the same result as if you declared it as a friend in the class, and defined the function immediately outside the class (but inside any surrounding namespace).

Comment: @Andrew It's a homework and we need to write prototypes bodies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `operator>>` is a friend to `MainClass`, it's not associated with a specific instance of `MainClass` (i.e., it doesn't receive a `this` pointer).

Therefore, when you try to do:

```
map.insert(myMap::value_type(name, sample) );
```

The compiler doesn't know what instance's `map` member you want to refer to. Clearly, in this case, you mean:

```
mainc.map.insert(myMap::value_type(name, sample));
```

...since `mainc` is the instance of `MainClass` whose reference you received as the destination for the data you read.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide what your operator>> does and what instance of "map" memeber it uses.

Comment: >> does bunch of stuff which is irrelevant to this. How do can I declare instances of "map"? I thought that when I call map.foo(), it will be applied to map data member.

Comment: operator>> is not a *member* of your class, that's why it gets a reference to your class instance as the second argument.
So when you address an instance data member of MainClass, you need 
to provide an instance of MainClass, so change your "insert" statement to "mainc.map.insert".